# How to wrap these decorated functions into a class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, slack-api, python-decorators

I am attempting to wrap V2 of the Slack API into a class so that I can keep information about my bot encapsulated. Here is one of their example snippets:

```py
import slack

slack_token = os.environ["SLACK_API_TOKEN"]
rtmclient = slack.RTMClient(token=slack_token)

@slack.RTMClient.run_on(event='message')
def say_hello(**payload):
    data = payload['data']
    if 'Hello' in data['text']:
        channel_id = data['channel']
        thread_ts = data['ts']
        user = data['user']

        webclient = payload['web_client']
        webclient.chat_postMessage(
            channel=channel_id,
            text="Hi <@{}>!".format(user),
            thread_ts=thread_ts
        )

rtmclient.start()
```

My understanding here is that this `say_hello` function is being passed into the slack object because of the decorator, so if I were to wrap this into a class, that function isn't really sitting inside my class. How do I wrap the `say_hello` function for it to be able to call methods and reference properties that belonged to an instance of my class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at how decorators work!

```py
def decorator_factory(f):                                                                                                                                                                     
    def decoration(*args, **kwargs):                                                                                                                                                          
        print('before')                                                                                                                                                                       
        r = f(*args, **kwargs)                                                                                                                                                                
        print('after')                                                                                                                                                                        
        return r                                                                                                                                                                              
    return decoration                                                                                                                                                                         

@decorator_factory                                                                                                                                                                            
def inc(i):                                                                                                                                                                                   
    '''                                                                                                                                                                                       
    >>> inc(23)                                                                                                                                                                               
    before                                                                                                                                                                                    
    after                                                                                                                                                                                     
    42                                                                                                                                                                                        
    '''                                                                                                                                                                                       
    return i + 1
```

There may be a better, canonical way to achieve what you want, but this would do the job:

```py
class Client():                                                                                                                                                                               

    def __init__(self):                                                                                                                                                                       
        slack.RTMClient.run_on(event='message')(self.decorated)                                                                                                                               

    def decorated(self, x, y, z):                                                                                                                                                                      
        pass
```

Comment: @Stoopkid I'm facing the same problem, how did you apply this answer?

Answer (score 1):

They key is not to use the decorator at all.

From Markus' solution, just call the "run_on" function directly, before you call "start" function, similar to the below:

```
rtmclient = slack.RTMClient(token=self.Token)
rtmclient.run_on(event='message')(self.handle_command)
rtmclient.start()
```