# Python, reference class instance/method in decorated function

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, python-decorators

I'm having a hard time finding a way to reference class instances in a decorator function.

```
import json
import time
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from main_UI import Ui_ApplicationWindow
from slack import RTMClient

class WorkerThread(QThread):
  finished = pyqtSignal(str)   

  def __init__(self):
    QThread.__init__(self)  
    self.rtm_client = RTMClient(token="xoxp...") 

  def run(self):     
    self.rtm_client.start()

  @RTMClient.run_on(event="message")
  def say_hello(**payload):
    data = payload['data']
    if (len(data) != 0):
      if "text" in data:          
        text = data['text']         
        self.finished.emit(str(text))  


class ApplicationWindow(QMainWindow):

  def __init__(self):
    super(ApplicationWindow, self).__init__()
    self.ui = Ui_ApplicationWindow()
    self.ui.setupUi(self)   
    self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.start_rtm)      

  def start_rtm(self):
    self.thread = WorkerThread()
    self.thread.finished.connect(self.update)
    self.thread.start()

  @pyqtSlot(str)
  def update(self, data):
    self.ui.label.setText(data)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    myWindow = ApplicationWindow()
    myWindow.show()
    app.exec_()
```

So in `say_hello` since it can't take `self` as an argument, I'm not able to use `self.finished.emit(text)` at the end of the function.

How can I reference a class instance/function using `self` in `say_hello`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, You can not. Instead of using the [`@RTMClient.run_on()`](https://github.com/slackapi/python-slackclient/blob/master/slack/rtm/client.py#L139) decorator, use the [`RTMClient.on()`](https://github.com/slackapi/python-slackclient/blob/master/slack/rtm/client.py#L149) function to register it.

```py
import threading
import asyncio

from slack import RTMClient

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets


class SlackClient(QtCore.QObject):
    textChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)

    def start(self):
        RTMClient.on(event="message", callback=self.say_hello)
        threading.Thread(target=self._start_loop, daemon=True).start()

    def _start_loop(self):
        loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
        asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
        slack_token = "xoxb-...."
        rtm_client = RTMClient(token=slack_token)
        rtm_client.start()

    def say_hello(self, **payload):
        data = payload["data"]
        if data:
            if "text" in data:
                text = data["text"]
                self.textChanged.emit(text)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    client = SlackClient()

    button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Start")
    textedit = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit()

    button.clicked.connect(client.start)
    client.textChanged.connect(textedit.appendPlainText)

    w = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(w)
    lay.addWidget(button)
    lay.addWidget(textedit)
    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Update:**

```py
import sys
import threading
import asyncio

from slack import RTMClient

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from main_UI import Ui_ApplicationWindow


class SlackClient(QtCore.QObject):
    textChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)

    def start(self):
        RTMClient.on(event="message", callback=self.say_hello)
        threading.Thread(target=self._start_loop, daemon=True).start()

    def _start_loop(self):
        loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
        asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
        slack_token = "xoxb-...."
        rtm_client = RTMClient(token=slack_token)
        rtm_client.start()

    def say_hello(self, **payload):
        data = payload["data"]
        if data:
            if "text" in data:
                text = data["text"]
                self.textChanged.emit(text)


class ApplicationWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ApplicationWindow, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_ApplicationWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.client = SlackClient()
        # connections
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.client.start)
        self.client.textChanged.connect(self.ui.label.setText)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myWindow = ApplicationWindow()
    myWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I feel this is a bit challenging for me to apply. I have one `ApplicationWindow` class and a `WorkerThread` class which run independently. Could you apply your concept in my context please? I updated my code..

Comment: nicee it works like a charm! thank you. In my case I used `class WorkerThread(QThread):` When I use `threading.Thread(target=self._start_loop, daemon=True).start()` in the class, am I using two threads?

Comment: @bbusdriver Yes. Do not use QThread, it can bring you some inconvenience.

Comment: sorry i'm new to this world how come using QThread bring some inconvenience? So you recommend to use QObject and use `threading.Thread` everytime?

Comment: @bbusdriver In this case it is easier to use threading. TL; DR; the threads do not depend on the technology/library/language but on the OS, so the thread handled by threading is the same as that handled by QThread, so the use of one or the other in general is indifferent. But QThread allows you to move a QObject to a new context, which if you do not know how to handle it (as I suppose you do not know because you are a beginner) you can modify elements of the QObject from a thread to which it does not belong. so it is better to use threading and just running the loop there will avoid problems.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you cannot self since that is a global variable, not a class one.

```
from slack import RTMClient

class WorkerThread(QThread):
    finished = pyqtSignal(dict)

    def __init__(self):
        QThread.__init__(self)
        self.rtm_client = RTMClient(token="xoxp-....")    

    def run(self):
        self.rtm_client.start()

    @RTMClient.run_on(event="message")
    def say_hello(**payload):
        data = payload['data']
        if (len(data) != 0):
            if "text" in data:          
                text = data['text']                      
                WorkerThread.finished.emit(text)  <--- using self impossible
```

I suggest that you make such variable private by appending two underscores at the beginning (`__my_private_var`)

Comment: Hi, so `__finished = pyqtSignal(dict)` ?

Comment: Yes. Did it work? Be sure to change the call inside the ``say_hello`` method (``WorkerThread.__finished.emit(text) ``)

Comment: no can't make it private because `finished` is accessed from another class

Comment: Seems like this guy had the [same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56761860/how-to-wrap-these-decorated-functions-into-a-class). But I can't apply it, can you help?

Comment: Well, in that case, don't. Does it work making it public?

Comment: no it gives me `'PyQt5.QtCore.pyqtSignal' object has no attribute 'emit'` `emit` works when it is used in the function where I can use `self`

Comment: Bu that error means that object ``finished`` or this thing ``pyqtSignal(dict)`` (is that a class?) has not any method called ``emit``. Please can you provide a GitHub link to take a look at your code? It'd be way easier.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200427/discussion-between-tomas-denis-reyes-sanchez-and-bbusdriver).