# python, closing loop and slack client

Tags: python, pyqt5, slack-api

I'm listening to the slack channel via slack's `RTM API`, but when I try to stop listening to it, I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client_ws.py", line 227, in receive
    msg = await self._reader.read()
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\streams.py", line 631, in read
    return await super().read()
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\streams.py", line 591, in read
    await self._waiter
concurrent.futures._base.CancelledError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\slack\rtm\client.py", line 372, in _read_messages
    message = await self._websocket.receive(timeout=1)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client_ws.py", line 227, in receive
    msg = await self._reader.read()
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\async_timeout\__init__.py", line 45, in __exit__
    self._do_exit(exc_type)

  File "c:\Users\she jong shon\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.10.41019\pythonFiles\lib\python\old_ptvsd\ptvsd\_vendored\pydevd\_pydev_bundle\pydev_monkey.py", line 667, in __call__
    ret = self.original_func(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\threading.py", line 884, in _bootstrap
    self._bootstrap_inner()
  File "C:\Python36\lib\threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\fbs_runtime\excepthook\__init__.py", line 84, in run_with_except_hook
    run_original(*args2, **kwargs2)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\she jong shon\Desktop\RTC36\src\main\python\main.py", line 303, in start_loop
    self.rtm_client.start()
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\slack\rtm\client.py", line 198, in start
    return self._event_loop.run_until_complete(future)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 484, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\slack\rtm\client.py", line 340, in _connect_and_read
    await self._read_messages()
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\slack\rtm\client.py", line 374, in _read_messages
    if not self._websocket.closed:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'closed'
```

Basically, I have a button that calls `stop()` which should stop the `rtm_client` and exit the thread. 
Am I getting errors because I did not properly exit the loop?

```
import sys
import threading
import asyncio

from slack import RTMClient

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from main_UI import Ui_ApplicationWindow


class SlackClient(QtCore.QObject):
    textChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)
    terminated = pyqtSignal()

    def start(self):
        threading.Thread(target=self._start_loop, daemon=True).start()

    def _start_loop(self):
        RTMClient.on(event="message", callback=self.say_hello)  
        loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
        asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
        slack_token = "xoxb-...."
        self.rtm_client = RTMClient(token=slack_token)
        self.rtm_client.start()

    def say_hello(self, **payload):
        data = payload["data"]
        if data:
            if "text" in data:
                text = data["text"]
                self.textChanged.emit(text)

    def stop(self):
        self.rtm_client.stop()  
        self.terminated.emit()

class ApplicationWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ApplicationWindow, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_ApplicationWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.client = SlackClient()
        # connections
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.client.start)
        self.ui.stopButton.clicked.connect(self.client.stop)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myWindow = ApplicationWindow()
    myWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I think you have mess in code. `QThread` creates thread but you use `threading` to create another thread inside thread created by `QThread`. You create `asyncio` loop but you also use `start()` to run it without using `asyncio`.

Comment: thanks. yeah, new to python world. So what do you recommend?

Comment: @bbusdriver Why do you use QThread?, in my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58245061/6622587 do not put it and explain why it is unnecessary.

Comment: hi eyllanesc, I ended up using it because the progress bar was not initiating with `QObject`

Comment: @bbusdriver mmmm, ...., It smells like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), why don't you ask in this case about the QProgressBar and provide the MRE that I've asked for (that I've begged you)? that you don't know how to use the QProgressBar in my initial code does not imply that you should use QThread. Please use `@username`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I am willing to switch back to `QObject`.. and work on the progress bar when this problem is solved first.